Create a Multipartresolver bean in Spring-6
in spring5  we can create a bean like below.
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize">
        <value>1073741824</value>
    </property>
</bean>

but this CommonsMultipartResolver is dropped in spring-6.
so we have org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver for multipart file uploads. but how to set maxUploadSize property, as this property is not available in above class?

Please follow the JEE docs or check StandardServletMultipartResolver docs.
You can use web.xml
<multipart-config>
 <location>/tmp</location>
 <max-file-size>26214400</max-file-size>
 <max-request-size>31457280</max-request-size>
 <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>

Or javax servlet annotations:
@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, 
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
// ...

Or spring config:
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
   // ...
   @Override
   protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
     // Optionally also set maxFileSize, maxRequestSize, fileSizeThreshold
     registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp"));
   }
 }

